# Box OAuth2: return 404 error, when click "Return to the App" button in the login page

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

I retrieved HTTP 404 error, When I clicked "Return to the App" button in the Box OAuth2 login page.

And I used the fiddler to check the HTTP request,
it sent "GET https://api.box.com/oauth2/", returned 404 Not Found.

So I am not sure that "Return to App" button like "cancel login" functionality or others?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Is it a Box 404 page or coming from somewhere else? Can you provide a screenshot of the 404 page?

Comment: seanrose, I found that it is because we not set redirect_uri in the application OAuth2 setting. :)

Comment: great–I'll add that as answer for anyone who has the issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

redirect_uri needs to be set in the settings of your app in order for the page to know where to redirect back to.